# SAPUI5 Hybrid App - How do I implement logout functionality?

Tags: cordova, sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I've applied the following logout functionality to my SAPUI5 Hybrid/Cordova app.

```
onLogout: function () {

   if (typeof sap.hybrid !== 'undefined') {
      sap.Logon.core.deleteRegistration(this.logonUnregisterSuccessCallback(), this.errorCallback());
   }
},

logonUnregisterSuccessCallback: function (){
      sap.Logon.core.loadStartPage();
}
```

deleteRegistration() works, but loadStartPage() takes me straight back into the app without forcing me to login again.

I need to force the login to give the user a method to switch usernames.